# Which one is correct in a sentence: "Thanks, name" or "Thanks name,"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Which one is correct in formal email writing? In Google, I could not find the complete sentence which includes name.

> - Thanks David, for letting me know.
>     or
> - Thanks, David for letting me know.

Comment: Hello, Ask_SO, how about option #3?

Comment: @Rattler - Please let me know.

Comment: @Rattler  'Thanks, David, for letting me know.'
Am I right?

Comment: @Rattler Thanks!